# installing packages to Mac desktop after using conda virtual environment

Tags: pip, anaconda

A few weeks ago I started using a virtual environment in anaconda to code. I did download a bunch of packages into that environment.

For some reason, now when I use pip to install packages, it installs directly into the virtual environment and not onto my desktop python.

When running sudo pip install --upgrade pip, it comes up with the following statement:
"Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages (18.1)"
Which if not obvious, is my virtual environment. This is the same when I try install other packages. (depending on whether the packages are up to date)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your 'desktop python'? Do you mean the system Python?

Comment: Yeah, Python Idle

Comment: During installation did you choose to add Anaconda's path to your system path [(near the bottom of this page)](http://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/mac-os/)? That's usually how people want it to work, if they want to develop on Anaconda and leave the system Python untouched. If you want to keep working with the system Python you probably want to remove that path entry; you can still access Anaconda via the Navigator and there should also be some sort of script installed to get it at the command line - I'm not that familiar with the details of a Mac installation.